# npm webpack babel-loader error: Uncaught TypeError: n(...) is not a function

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to install babel-loader to be used with webpack

I ran this command:

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Which installed:

babel-loader@8.0.2
@babel/core@7.1.0

and webpack is 4.19.0

webpack.config.js

```html
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then i tried to make a simple change on a javascript file just to check that it is using ES6

```html
//before
module.exports = function(ngModule) {
  require('./kcd-hello')(ngModule);
};

//currently
export default ngModule => {
  require('./kcd-hello')(ngModule);
};
```

but I am getting the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n(...) is not a function
```

Can someone check what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Your change isn't equivalent. You'd also need to adjust all of the places you actually use that file, but since you haven't included that, it is hard to say more.

Comment: In which way is not equivalent?

Comment: Believe it is working. Is my lack of knowledge that lead me to think the babel loader is not working.

If I use, const as
    const vm = this;

or even an arrow function inside for instance a directive:
    ngModule.directive('kcdHello', () => {.... }

it works fine. but for some reason the 
    export default ngModule => {
This i got from a tutorial with one year. Perhaps it is out of date and actually i don't understand what is doing.

Do you have an idea what would be equivalent?

Comment: I would need to see the how you're actually importing that function.